# How to get alphabets only from given albha-numberic word in java?

Tags: java

sorry for this if this is a silly question.but i need to know about this.

If i have a word like alphabets,numeric and special charters. I need to extract alphabets only.No need for numeric and special characters.I need to know is there default function is there in Java to split characters only?

```
eg.String word="te123@#st";
```

I need **test** only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");`

Answer (score 3):

This solution works with accentued/non-ascii caracters :

```
"te123@#st\néàø_".replaceAll("[\\p{Digit}\\p{Punct}\\p{Space}]", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

This will remove all non alphanumeric characters, but it will still remove accented characters.

```
 String word = "te123@#st";
 word = word.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]", "");  
 // or word = word.replaceAll("[\\P{Alpha}]", "");
```

See [apidoc reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
String word = "te123@#st";
word = word.replaceAll("[\\W\\d._]", "");
```

Comment: @gefei What seems wrong about it? it replaces all non word characters and underscore (which word characters allow)

Comment: I executed it, and I got `@#`

Comment: this outputs these two characters "@#" and the OP asked for alphanumeric only e.g. "test"?

Comment: @gefei you were right i was negating the char set, I fixed the solution

Comment: @gefei underscore is included in the charset

Comment: @KevinBowersox if  `word=="te_123@#st"`, then the output is `te123st`. with digits

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    word = word.replaceAll("\\P{Alpha}", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
word = word.replaceAll("[\\d@#_]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** I won't make this complicated using `Regex`, but **will use inbuilt Java functionalities to answer this.**

**-** First use `subString()` method to get the "abcd" part of the String, then use `toCharArray()` method to break the `String` into `char` elements, then use `Character class's` `isDigit()` method to know whether its a digit or not.

```
public class T1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        String s = "te123@#st";

        String str = s.substring(0,4);
        System.out.println(str);
        String tempStr = new String();
        char[] cArr = str.toCharArray();

        for(char a :cArr){

            if(Character.isAlphabetic(a)){

                System.out.println(a+" is a alphabet");
                tempStr = tempStr + a;
            }else{

                System.out.println(a+" is not a alphabet");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The extracted String is: "+tempStr);
             }
     }
```